# UTC DateTime on IIS web server does not match UTC time on browser side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, date, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.Net app hosted on a popular ASP.Net hosting provider, in which I am storing the forms authentication expiration DateTime in a cookie. When the request returns to client/browser `almost instantaneously`, I determine the local time corresponding to this UTC datetime in cookie using code below. I am storing year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds in the above cookie and not a string value of date time.

*JavaScript Code*

```
var c = getCookie("xyz");//getCookie is a custom function for getting cookie value
if (c) {
var dateArray = c.split(",");
//cDate is local date time on browser for server-side UTC date time
var cDate = new Date(Date.UTC(dateArray[0], dateArray[1], dateArray[2],
                          dateArray[3], dateArray[4], dateArray[5], dateArray[6]));
 //nowDate is current local date time on browser side
 var nowDate = new Date();//this should be very close to 4 minutes behind cDate
}
```

I am using forms authentication timeout of 4 minutes. Since the request returns almost instantly, so in above code `nowDate` should be close to 4 minutes behind `cDate`, but it is always one minute less than expected i.e. 3 minutes behind. Even if I set forms authentication timeout value to something other than 4 minutes, I am still finding that `nowDate` is always one minute less than expected value as compared to `cDate`.

**Question**: What could be the reason for this strange time difference even when the request is almost instantaneous? I could not find any possible reason other than that the web server may have some incorrect time settings. I tried different values of forms authentication timeout values but the diff is always 1 minute.

*C# code to store Ticket Expiration in UTC*

```
 void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.Request.IsAuthenticated && Context.User.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Forms")
    {
        FormsIdentity identity = (FormsIdentity)Context.User.Identity;
        DateTime utcDateTime = identity.Ticket.Expiration.ToUniversalTime();
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(utcDateTime.Year);
        sb.Append(",");
        sb.Append(utcDateTime.Month - 1);//since JavaScript uses a 0 based index for month
        sb.Append(",");
        sb.Append(utcDateTime.Day);
        sb.Append(",");
        sb.Append(utcDateTime.Hour);
        sb.Append(",");
        sb.Append(utcDateTime.Minute);
        sb.Append(",");
        sb.Append(utcDateTime.Second);
        sb.Append(",");
        sb.Append(utcDateTime.Millisecond);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("xyz", sb.ToString());
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
}
```

*Forms Authentication configuration*

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" name="ABCAuth" 
       protection="All" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="4"
       ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40" />
 </authentication>
```

Comment: You need to also set the client-side date to UTC - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate

Comment: @jeff, If you look at my code under JavaScript, you will notice that I am using Date.UTC function, which returns the milliseconds since 1970-1-1  for a UTC date. So the UTC date from server-side is being converted to local date on browser side correctly.

Comment: @jeff, I can either compare UTC date from server side  with browser UTC date , OR UTC server side date converted to local browser date with browse local date.  I am using the latter, so it should not matter.

Comment: if the diff is always 1 minute, it's less likely that server time is incorrect. even if it is incorrect, diff should change when you change timeout. could it be that your timeout wasn't used at all?

Comment: Timeout is used automatically by the forms authentication module in Asp.Net pipeline, since all that happens without writing any code. I am shocked by this situation since it seems too mysterious. Time diff always being the same points to the fact that time on server is out of sync with real time by 1 minute. But that is just my best guess.

Comment: If you suspect server time is incorrect, you can check server time from response header using chrome or your preferred browser and compare it with your client machine time.